# Time Paradox on the Stack Overflow Tour Page

Tags: support, status-completed, timestamps

The demo question on the [Tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) "Why are function pointers and data pointers incompatible in C/C++?"

- was asked on September 10<sup>th</sup> 2012 at 20:21,
- has an accepted answer that was posted September 10<sup>th</sup> 2012 at 20:26,
- and the second answer was posted on February 7<sup>th</sup> 2011 at 18:00, ***one and half years before the question was asked!***

[image: Time vortex]

`<joke>`If it's not going to be fixed, can I has silver version of "Informed" badge for spotting this?`</joke>`

Comment: It’s there in [the real question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358843/why-are-function-pointers-and-data-pointers-incompatible-in-c-c), too.

Comment: [Jerry Coffin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4924728/456814) is ***clearly a time traveler***, and could bend the very fabric of space-time to answer the question from 1.5 years in the past. Or aliens. I blame aliens.

Comment: Clearly a two-digit year problem.  The question must have been asked in 1912.

Comment: @Cupcake: I am *not* a time traveler. I am merely chrono-synclastically infundibulated. But yes, the chrono-synclastic infidibulum was apparently built by the Tralfamadorians.

Comment: Testers, behold the mighty Time vortex! This is how a bug report should look like.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Here is the actual question used in the about page:

[Why are function pointers and data pointers incompatible in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358843/why-are-function-pointers-and-data-pointers-incompatible-in-c-c)

> [image]

And there is really [an answer posted one and a half years before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4924728/) the question was asked, [because the question was merged](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12358843/revisions).

> [image]

If you are going to get a silver badge, I'm gonna get a gold one.

Comment: You, sir, deserve the "Sherlock" badge.

Comment: But here, the merged question was asked before the question in about page. How come that should be merge?

Comment: @Hemang Duplicate/merge is less about "which one was asked first" and more about "which one has better answers".

Comment: It’s actually less about which one has better answers (they get merged, after all) and more about which question was asked the best, has the most attention, and has a better accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

## Time Travel Forbidden Within SO City Limits

Animuson [just marked this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/262662/6) as `[status-completed]`. Why? Because the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) no longer uses the [Time Vortex question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358843/why-are-function-pointers-and-data-pointers-incompatible-in-c-c) as an example.

## Restoring the Space-Time Continuum

Instead of using the confusing time paradox example, the tour page now uses this space-time compliant question instead:

- [Do Swift-based applications work on OS X 10.9/iOS 7 and lower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-apps-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower)

[image]

<sub>[Delorean DMC-12 side](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeLorean_Motor_Company#mediaviewer/Datei:Delorean_DMC-12_side.jpg) by Kevin Abato. Resized and crossed out, added to question image.</sub>

Lesson? Don't go time traveling around Stack Overflow. Unless, of course, you're using Git.

Comment: I actually removed the other question from the tour page shortly after this was posted. I added the tag so this will stop showing up in the community bulletin because it's not something useful the community needs to keep looking at. ;P